# Как подключить jQuery к файлу Js

Tags: javascript

Есть файл js. в котором содержится код :

```
$('.call_popup').click(function() {
    $('.popup').toggleClass('open');
});
$('.popup_header i').click(function() {
    $('.popup').removeClass('open'); 
})
```

Знак `$` если я не ошибаюсь это библиотека jQuery, которая не подключена к данному файлу. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу подключить эту библиотеку?

Comment: http://w3.org.ua/jquery/podklyuchenie-biblioteki-jquery-4-sposoba/

Comment: А можно ли подключить к самому js файлу?

Comment: Можете скопировать содержимое файла jquery.js и вставить его в ваш файл скрипта перед вашим кодом.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  //Код
});
```

Comment: @Виталий_Шебаниц "undefined"==typeof jQuery.migrateMute

Comment: @Виталий_Шебаниц Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
ошибка в консоли

Comment: Вы должны строку подключения jquery поставить перед строкой подключения самого скрипта. И посмотрите путь к js скрипту.